# Internal nginx besides a k3s setup on one vps

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, vps

currently I run a nginx on a vps and I want to install k3s. The vps has two public reachable IP addresses and I want that the nginx on the vps itself only react to one specific of these two addresses.

Where can I realize that I can run the internal nginx besides the k3s?

Comment: do you mean k8s?

Comment: no I mean k3s https://k3s.io/

Comment: neat learn something new every day

Comment: you want to run nginx as a proxy for containers that are running in the back ground  on some other port? for that I would say take a look at ningx proxyPass settings. you could make a location{} that proxyes your svc

Comment: no I want to split traffic from one IP to an internal nginx and the other traffic to k3s

Comment: Hello, I have some difficulties to understand your question. Could you please clarify for me what exactly your want to achieve? Do you want to have a K3S cluster where `Nginx` Pod is accessible only through the one of the 2 IP's?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with NodePort. You can create Nginx Service in K3S of the NodePort type.

Node port will expose your service to host on specific port.

References:

- Kubernetes docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types
- Rancher docs: https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/v1.6-migration/expose-services/